# $mysqli->prepare returns false if data fields are blank

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

There are 4 fields in the form and 2 of them are allow null, so if a user doesn't fill those fields, INSERT would fail as `$mysqli->prepare` will return false.

Email address and phone number are not cumpolsary in following form.

[image: Email address and phone number are not cumpolsary]

So, is there any way to send the blank fields and still insert the data for other filled fields.

```
function newcontact()
    {
        $mysqli = connect();
        $query = "INSERT INTO contacts( first_name, last_name, email, phone_no, contact_by )Values( '$this->first_name', '$this->last_name',
                    '$this->email', $this->phone, $this->user_id)"; 
        //die( $query );
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
        if( $stmt->execute() )
        {
            $mysqli->close();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you use $mysqli->prepare?

Comment: i am using it as an object. The function connect() returns new mysqli(.....) object.

Comment: though the question was "why do you use it"

Comment: Ok, i am not using bind param at the moment, just wanted to test query.

Comment: go on, use bind param and error will disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- if user don't fill these fields, not NULLS but **empty strings** will be put into query.
- and thus cause syntax error, as `Values('', '', '', , )` is a sure error.
- you are using prepare wrong way.
- you don't have mysqli error reporting set

Add this line right before mysqli_connect

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

and make your query actually use placeholders and bind param.

And everything will work. Yet if not, you will be notified of the exact error.

Comment: i am trying mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); on some other query but it returns bool value. How can i see the actual message.

Comment: you should call this operator **not on query** but only **once**, before connect.

Answer (score 0):

when using an prepared statement you don't put the values in the query you provide placheholders instead and bind the parameters.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

if you want to put the values in the query use the function `query()` 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php